# Is there a View like this in android? (picture attached)

Tags: android, view, expand

I'm not a English speaker, please don't be upset to my poor English.

I think app is inconvenient when it has a lot of activities.
So I think up this View to reduce number of activities.

[before touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e46mJ.jpg)

[after touched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4GSq.jpg)

When I touch the "card view 1", it "expands", and shows a fragment inside the card view 1.
And, important point, I can see or touch "card view 2" by just scrolling down.(In other word, expanded card view 1, fragment inside card view 1 and unexpanded card view 2 is in the same activity)

I tried to find a View like this, but I couldn't.
Please let me know if there is view like this. thanks.

Comment: why need fragments, just place your view in each card and make visibility gone at start

Comment: "I tried to find a View like this, but I couldn't" -- a `View` like *what*? If you are looking for a vertically-scrolling list of cards, use `RecyclerView` and `CardView`, both in the Android Support Library. Expansion of a card may be simply a matter of changing the visibility of some of its contents. Or, look into [expandable widgets](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=expand).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one with RecyclerView and CardView. [Here is the solution.](https://medium.com/@akshay.shinde/cardview-expand-collapse-cd10916bb77c)